# Telerik date picker

Tags: datepicker, telerik

I am new to telerik UI control.I need some clarifications regarding datepicker title attribute.my question is how to add title property to a telerik datepicker.I tried to add tittle using htmlAttributes function,but the title should not be applied for datepicker control instead of that the title has been applied to its(datepicker) div tag when we render the UI.kindly provide the solution to add title to datepicker controls.

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to add and customize the datepicker? That will make it easier for others to provide solutions.

Comment: Is it Telerik UI for Web Forms or MVC? Which are you referring to?

Comment: Telerik UI for MVC

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 elem.kendoDatePicker({
                       format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                           value: raportDate})
```